# Appending Feature Class from Geodatbase to another using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, append

I'm trying to write a python script to load feature class from an existing geodatabase to a new one, here is my script:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os
import traceback

#Set up workspace
outworkspace = r"C:\user\Geodatabases\Gdb_mena_v3.gdb"
workspace = r"C:\user\Geodatabases\gdb_4.3.0_v2.gdb"

arcpy.env.workspace = workspace

#get a list of feature classes
featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in featureclasses:

    shp_file = fc

    if shp_file == "MAP":
    arcpy.Append_management(os.path.join(workspace, shp_file), "C:\\user\\Geodatabases\\Gdb_mena_v3.gdb\\MAP", "NO_TEST", "","")

    print('Your load is done')

    else: print('Error reading data')
print "Finished!"
```

when I run the script I get this message:

```
 Error reading data
 Error reading data
 Error reading data
 Error reading data
 Error reading data
 Your load is done
 Error reading data
 Error shape file did not get read
 Finished!
```

Note that in my first geodatabase I have 7 features classes

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, are you indenting after your if statement, if shp_file == "MAP":?

Comment: @artwork21, Yes

Comment: I don't think this will help, but I don't think you need to join your workspace to your shp_file as you have already set your env.workspace variable. You could do os.path.join on your out fc though. os.path.join(outworkspace,"MAP")

Comment: Your error message does not necessary mean an error has occurred, rather just the "MAP" fc was not found.  Looks like your fc was found on the 6 iteration.  Do you have a fc named "MAP" in the other destination gdb to append to?

Comment: @artwork21, I think the my "MAP" fc was found , i checked the new gdb and the feature class "MAP" was appended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my comment noted, your code logic is correct, just your error messaging may of been misleading "Error reading data".  "Error reading data" could be renamed to `"other fc found: {}".format(shp_file)` or just remove the entire else condition.